# How to give a sequece of numpy array as input to CNN

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, tf.keras

How can I reshape a sequence of arrays of shape (90,30,1662)? Meaning 90 arrays with 30 frames each and 1662 keypoints for each frames.And 90 array meaning 30 videos of numpy arrays for a word with 30 frames per video.

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test=train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.05)
x_train.shape ---->(85, 30, 1662)


from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard


model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(64, return_sequences=True, activation='relu', input_shape=(30,1662)))
model.add(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, activation='relu'))
model.add(LSTM(64, return_sequences=False, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(actions.shape[0], activation='softmax'))
```

How can I add CNN before the LSTM?

Answer (score 1):

Reference: https://machinelearningmastery.com/cnn-long-short-term-memory-networks/

You can add CNN model first(with input shape=(30,90,1622)), and use LTSM model to encapsulate CNN model.

It will look like this:

```
cnn = Sequential()
cnn.add(Conv2D(your output size, (your filter size,your filter size), 
    activation='relu', padding='same', input_shape=(30,90,1622)))
cnn.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
cnn.add(Flatten())
model = Sequential()
model.add(TimeDistributed(cnn, ...)) # convert to LTSM type
model.add(LSTM(..))
model.add(Dense(...))
```

Comment: I tried what u requested

Comment: model = Sequential()

model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(3, (2,2), activation='relu', padding='same', 
     input_shape= (30,90,1622))))

model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))

model.add(LSTM(64, return_sequences=True, activation='relu'))

model.add(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, activation='relu'))

model.add(LSTM(64, return_sequences=False, activation='relu'))

model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))

model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))

model.add(Dense(actions.shape[0], activation='softmax'))

Comment: am getting an error     ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv2d_3 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, 
found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 1662)

Comment: check this: https://keras.io/api/layers/recurrent_layers/time_distributed/
You may build conv2d layer before going time distributed function.